# What does the Interface object means in the function parameters

Tags: php, laravel, oop, yii

I am not able to understand what is the meaning of having any model or interface object into the method parameters. 
For example,

```
public function checkRights(CommentInterface $comment)
{
    return true;
}
```

so here what does CommentInterface do? why we are not only passing $comment here? How do you name this kind of thing in programming language?

I am new to object oriented php
Thanks.

Comment: It's a type hint. It means `$comment` has to be an object that implements the `CommentInterface` interface. See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration).

Answer (score -1):

This is called as **Type Hinting**.

**Type hinting** forces you to only pass objects of a particular type. This prevents you from passing incompatible values, and creates a standard if you're working with a team etc.,

check the following example:

```
class Profile {
private $setting;
public function __construct(Setting $setting)
    {
        $this->setting = $setting;
    }
}
```

Because we need to use the $setting object inside the function, we inject/pass/type-hint it as a parameter.

Comment: No, that is not DI. `CommentInterface` is a simple type hint, and not all type hints refer to DI